# What is the purpose of the Zip64 'end of central directory locator'?

Tags: zip, file-format

In the [Zip64 format](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), there is a header called

> Zip64 end of central directory locator

that contains the offset to the zip64 end of central directory record. Why would you need this record when **you can search for the 'zip64 end of central directory' record by its magic number?**

EDIT: Please note that the only way to look up the locator is by looking up the magic number for locator. The point here is that why bother searching for the locator with the locator magic number in the first place when you can directly search the `zip64 end of central directory` record also by its magic number?

Comment: The zip64 end of central directory locator is 20 bytes before the end of central directory record so you don't have to search for it, just check if it is there. It is actually one of the saner records in an unsane spec.

Answer (score 7):

Navigating directly to a byte offset in a file is significantly faster than searching for a magic number.  Additionally, there is no guarantee that the magic number won't be found elsewhere within the data, which could cause the implementation to read from incorrect data if it starts reading from an invalid but "assumed correct" location.

After doing some additional implementation around this myself, I think the most significant thing to note is that "special purpose data may reside in the zip64 extensible data sector field" (following the Zip64 end of central directory record).  Multiple of these fields may exist, and each starts with a header ID of 2 bytes, followed by a data size of 4 bytes - followed by the actual "special purpose data" - allowing for multiple 2^32 bytes (4 GB) of data.  While this may seem extreme, doing so could certainly lead to needing to span disks between the locator and the "Zip64 end of central directory record".  Larger amounts of data here would not only take longer to scan for the signature, but the random chance of accidentally finding the minimal 4 byte / 32-bit "zip64 end of central directory" signature will increase with the length of the data.

"the only way to look up the locator is by looking up the magic number for locator" is not true.  If it exists, it should be immediately before the "End of central directory record".  Reading back 20 bytes from there, then reading the next 4 bytes should yield the "zip64 end of central dir locator signature" - which can be used as a sanity check (rather than scanning for it).

Comment: Did you know that the only way to look up the locator is to look for its magic number?

Comment: I'd need to re-read the spec, and think through this a little further (I really haven't done much with the zip64 portions of the spec yet) - but if it's the same as the rest of the spec, you can also find the locator by using relative offsets from other well-known locations (e.g. the end of the file, where the "end of central dir signature" does somewhat need to be searched for.

Comment: You still have the problem of how to find the `End of Central Directory` section, because it has this stupid variable-sized comment field... so it seems you have to scan until you find the magic number for `End of Central Directory`.

Comment: I seek to the end of the file - 22 bytes (assuming the comment field is empty) and check if the `PK\x05\x06` header matches, if not, I can seek backwards in chunks in a manner I deem 'efficient enough' looking for that header. Once I have the EOCD, I can read [the offset to start of central directory (CD) + CD length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#End_of_central_directory_record_(EOCD)), and seek to that offset. Seeking past the end of the CD in my test file gives me `PK\x06\x06`, which [is the EOCD64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#ZIP64)